# monitor network requests to see if a webpage has google analytics enabled

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-analytics, charles-proxy

Which requests should I monitor to see if a webpage has Google Analytics enabled and active?

Is is `analytics.js`?

Or maybe a GIF request to `www.google-analytics.com`, is that revealing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Universal Analytics, look for GIF image requests sent to the endpoint `google-analytics.com/collect`
 (cf. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#hits_hit_types_and_the_measurement_protocol).

Comment: And if you want to get fancy you could catch that request and insert a "debug" into the url (google-analytics.com/debug/collect... with al other parameters intact) to retrieve some additional information about the request in JSON format.